# NTLM Proxy Translator to Basic Auth or Oauth

Tags: oauth, proxy, basic-authentication, ntlm

I have some services (say S1 & S2) that I would like to connect them with a third party service (say S3) that uses NTLM authentication. My Problem is that I can use either Basic Auth or Oauth. I was wondering if there is a Proxy that can make this Authentication translation (From NTLM to BasicAuth).

```
|s1|<--|
       |--BasicAuth--> |Proxy| <--NTLM--> |s3|
|s2|<--|
```

For now, I am using Curl (--ntlm) to achieve that, but I would like to alter this as described.

S1 & S2 are running in a Debian Host.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manage to Solve that by installing [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/). It's a proxy that does pretty much what I described.

I configured the proxy as it is mentioned in [this blog post](http://blog.hoachuck.biz/blog/2013/03/21/howto-set-cntlm-on-mac-os-x/)

With the main difference that I set only the `Domain`, and comment in the `Password` and `User` arguments:

```
Domain      mySoapNTLMdomain
# Username
# Password  
# NOTE: Use plaintext password only at your own risk
# Use hashes instead. You can use a "cntlm -M" and "cntlm -H"
# command sequence to get the right config for your environment.
# See cntlm man page
# Example secure config shown below.
# PassLM
# PassNT
# PassNTLMv2
```

So I could be authorised by using Basic Authentication. e.g.

```
curl http://soap.mydomain:1234/my/path --proxy http://127.0.0.1:3128 --user soapuser:andpass --proxy-user soapuser:andpass
```